# javascript JSON : Sum two or more json having only numeric values with same keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript

I am new to Nodejs and typescript.I have below two jsons :

```
json1 = 
{
    "201809": 2,
    "metric": "headcount",
    "quarter1": 60,
    "careerLevelsGroups": [{
        "201809": 2,
        "quarter1": 60,
        "careerLevels": [{
                "201809": 2,
                "careerId": "careerId1",
                "quarter1": 60,
            },
            {
                "201809": 2,
                "careerId": "careerId2",
                "quarter1": 50,
            }
        ]
    }]
}

json2 = 
    {
        "201809": 3,
        "metric": "headcount",
        "quarter1": 100,
        "careerLevelsGroups": [{
            "201809": 7,
            "quarter1": 40,
            "careerLevels": [{
                    "201809": 9,
                    "careerId": "careerId1",
                    "quarter1": 30,
                },
                {
                    "201809": 8,
                    "careerId": "careerId2",
                    "quarter1": 30,
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

I want to sum all the numeric values associated with the same keys and produce a single json having the summed values of json1 and json2.

```
result = 
{
        "201809": 5,
        "metric": "headcount",
        "quarter1": 160,
        "careerLevelsGroups": [{
            "201809": 9,
            "quarter1": 100,
            "careerLevels": [{
                    "201809": 11,
                    "careerId": "careerId1",
                    "quarter1": 90,
                },
                {
                    "201809": 10,
                    "careerId": "careerId2",
                    "quarter1": 80,
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

I am trying to use a loop but i have too many such elements which i need to sum so can you please suggest a more optimised method to be used in Node.js

Comment: please include attempted script and expected output

Comment: i have added the expected result. i have not attempted any script yet as i am not able to get any other idea except use a loop. I don't want to use loop as i have 100s of these elements to be added.

Comment: I'd use a loop. I'd show some attempt to solve the problem too, you'll get an answer.

Comment: i recommend recursion. think of processing all the scalar members in the function and processing the object members as a reentrant call to the same function. i cannot easily type as im using my smartphone. hopefully this hint will help u

Comment: FYI, those are two javascript objects, not JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a `combine()` function which uses recursion for processing members of the JSON object. If it detects a `"number"` it combines it. If it detects an `"object"` it applies recursion to search for more `"number"` or `"object"` inside it. For any other type (e.g. `"string"`) it just leaves the values as is.

```js
function combine(acc, curr) {
  for (var key in acc) {
    switch (typeof(acc[key])) {
    case "number":
      acc[key] += curr[key];
      break;
    case "object":
      combine(acc[key], curr[key]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

var json1 = 
{
    "201809": 2,
    "metric": "headcount",
    "quarter1": 60,
    "careerLevelsGroups": [{
        "201809": 2,
        "quarter1": 60,
        "careerLevels": [{
                "201809": 2,
                "careerId": "careerId1",
                "quarter1": 60,
            },
            {
                "201809": 2,
                "careerId": "careerId2",
                "quarter1": 50,
            }
        ]
    }]
};

var json2 = 
    {
        "201809": 3,
        "metric": "headcount",
        "quarter1": 100,
        "careerLevelsGroups": [{
            "201809": 7,
            "quarter1": 40,
            "careerLevels": [{
                    "201809": 9,
                    "careerId": "careerId1",
                    "quarter1": 30,
                },
                {
                    "201809": 8,
                    "careerId": "careerId2",
                    "quarter1": 30,
                }
            ]
        }]
    };
    
var res = json1;
combine(res, json2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json1, undefined, 2));
```

Running the script produces the desired output. It should be a straightforward execise, to iterate through a series of these JSON objects to generate the result required.